# How to use Gurobi variables as a dictionary index in Gurobipy

Tags: gurobi, gurobipy

I want to model a problem that one of my variables needs to be used as an index of a dictionary in my constraints. Here is a minimal code that shows an example situation:

```
import gurobipy as gp

# Create a new Gurobi model
m = gp.Model()

my_dict = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
# Create decision variables
x = m.addVar(name="x")
m.update()
# Set objective function
m.setObjective(x, gp.GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Add constraints
m.addConstr(my_dict[x] >= 1, name="c1")

# Optimize the model
m.optimize()
```

in this example variable x in the constraint is used as the index of my_dict dictionary. However, the above code will result in the following error:

```
KeyError: <gurobi.Var x>
```

1. Is there a workaround to solve this and be able to use variables as indexes?

Another thing I also need for the above formulation is to be able to bound value of varialbe dicts to keys in the my_dict, e.g. if there were some options like this:

```
model.addVar(name='x', vtype=GRB.INTEGER, set=list(my_dict.keys()))
```

2. Is there a solution to this for bounding values to a specific set?

Comment: Not familiar with Gurobi, but don't you need to provide the index of the $x$-variable? Something like x = m.addVar(list(my_dict.keys(), name="x").

Comment: That's true, edited.

Comment: Does the answer below help in this? Also I understand it's example but constr in code doesn't make sense to me. Dictionary values are already greater than 1 and if x values are limited to keys the constr seems redundant.

Comment: No it doesn't. The above is just a dummy example. The question as mentioned is whether I can use variables in a dict or not?

Comment: @saeid-ghafouri, No, decision variables cant be used as index for any list/dictionary. you have to use it through a binary indexed over the key that turns to 1 for the key that matches with value of the variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First bounding of your vector variable $x$ over dict key set $I$
$ \sum_{i\in I} iz_i = x$
$ \sum_i z_i = 1$ where $z$ is binary.

The above 2 bounds $x$ to choose from $I$ and to use:
$\sum_{i\in I} z_iD_i$ where D is your dict.

**Sample code** below

```
D ={1:3, 2:5, 6:3.5, 8:4.2, 6:5.2}
model = Model('Index')
x = model.addVar(name='x')
z = model.addVars(D,vtype='b',name='z')

# constraints
C1 = model.addConstr(quicksum(d*z[d] for d in D) == x,name='C1')
C2 = model.addConstr(z.sum()==1, name='C2')
C3 = model.addConstr(quicksum(z[d]*D[d] for d in D) >= 2,name='C3')

obj = x
#obj = quicksum(z[d]*D[d] for d in D)
model.setObjective(obj,GRB.MAXIMIZE)
model.update()
model.optimize()
```